# Django DRF api does not return any value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create my first api using Django rest framework `DRF`. Here is my code:

in `views.py` :

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    # permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def queryset(self, request, pk=None):
        try:
            queryset = Post.objects.get(post_id=pk)
        except Analysis.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        if request.method == 'GET':
            serializer = PostSerializer(queryset)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

and in `urls.py`:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api/post/<int:pk>/post_analysis/', PostViewSet, basename='app_name')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

However this raises an error that

`The current path, api/post/698/post_analysis/, didn't match any of these.` or `Not Found: /api/post/698/post_analysis/`

But when I change url as follows, it returns none:

```
PostView = PostViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve'
})

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
  path('api/post/698/post_analysis/', PostView, name='app_name')
])
```

result is this:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

I noticed that the `queryset()` function of `PostViewSet` class is not being read.

Comment: Is it possible that the slash at the beginning of the URL is missing?
/api...

Comment: No even tried this one, but does not work

Comment: rename your queryset action method. It will conflict with other code.

Answer (score 2):

I would try implementing the sample ModelViewSet from the DRF documentation first and see if that works. For example:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

I'm no DRF expert, but your code looks quite different from the sample. For example, I'm not sure why you have an @action decorator on a queryset method, and also if you do use the queryset explicitly then I think you need to use the .all() or .filter() manager methods which generate querysets, not .get() which returns a single object. But if you have correctly defined your Serializer class then I believe the queryset is taken from the model you used to define the PostSerializer. ie:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

Comment: I just applied your point, but what I relalized class based viewset does not work, instead `@api_view(['GET']) def example_view(request, pk=None):` works

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying your urls.py file as follows:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/post/<int:pk>/post_analysis/', include(router.urls)),   

]
```

It may be a problem configuring the urls

Answer (score 0):

I could solved the problem with the help of both provided answers as follows:

in `views.py`:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @action(detail=True, methods=['GET'])
    def get_queryset(self, pk=None):
        try:
            pk = self.kwargs['pk']
            queryset = Post.objects.get(post_id=pk)
            return queryset
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

and in `urls.py`:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'', PostViewSet, basename='app_name')
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/post/<int:pk>/post_analysis/', include(router.urls)),

]
```

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful! That's the advantage of DRF, there are many ways to find the same solution according to your needs.